# Disable particular row value in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am trying to disable particular row in pickerView.

I have an array of strings for pickerView. I am appending values in array1 when user selects particular row.

After that I want to do that when user again opens pickerView if array1 has values of array, pickerView's that value should be disabled.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Option 1: Disabling an element**

You can give the title a greyed out style with the method [pickerView:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:)

Then you can change to a defaut value when that item is selected using [pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:)

**Option 2: Delete the item**

The second option would be to just remove the item from the possible options by adjusting your datasource.